# how to make ipa while you are using cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ipa

I want to know that how can I create ipa file, while I am using cocos2d, because it is first time I am making an ipa for cocos2d game, I saw three files instread of two in Build's folder,

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Buid-->Build & Archive.

Then Select Device in release mode...

Window-->Organizer-->Select your app in sidebar...Then Click Share..Change the identity to iPhone Developer.

That's all.

Comment: The question is in regards to using cocos2d rather than using Xcode; on Mac if you are using cocos2d-x there is no UI. Projects are built in the command line "cocos run -p ios" and deployed using "cocos deploy -p ios"; the latter creating a .app instead of .ipa hence his question.

Comment: With the latest cocos2d-x; there is a "proj.ios_mac" folder that is created which contains a <Project Name>.xcodeproj file.  If you open this file with Xcode, then the answer from Anish above makes sense and works.

Comment: This is the key I was missing -- after "Archive" other people said that a window appears to allow you to export, but nothing appeared for me. I had to go to the Organizer window to export to an .ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, make sure you have Xcode installed on your system; it can be acquired for free on the App Store.

In your cocos2d-x project folder, there should be a "proj.ios_mac" folder which will contain .xcodeproj folder.  From the command line, do "open .xcodeproj" or open the .xcodeproj with Xcode.

Xcode itself should then start.  Following the instructions provided by Anish, you should then be able to create a .ipa archive and distribute it to the App Store or via Ad Hoc to your test devices.